# Wrong results with variables operations in C

Tags: c, cs50, boolean-expression

I am trying to write this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float input;
    int quarters, cdimes, ldimes, nickels, pennies, left = 0, overleft, overleft2 = 0;
   
    do
    {
        input = get_float("Enter a positive value between 0 and 1: ");
    }
    while (input <= 0);
    int cents = round(input * 100);
    
    if (cents >= 25)
    {
        quarters = cents/25;
        **left = cents-(quarters*25);**
        printf ("Number of quarters is %i and the money left is %i", quarters, left);
    }
   else if (cents >= 10)
   {
        cdimes = cents/10; 
        **overleft2 = cents-cdimes*10;**
        printf ("Number of cdimes is %i and overleft2 is %i", cdimes, overleft2);
   }

         if (left >= 10)
        {   
        ldimes = left/10;
        overleft = left - ldimes*10;
        printf ("Number of ldimes is %i. Over left is %i", ldimes, overleft);
        }
```

But in the highlighted parts, the program is giving me wrong values. For example, when I input the number 0.6, the program multipley by 100 and round it (so now I have the number 60). Because 60 is greater than 25, it goes to the first if clause. However, when I want to subtract the number of quarters of the user's input, it does not give the correct value.
What can I do?

Comment: Consider calculating what's left over by using the modulo of cents and 25. This will give you the remainder

Comment: kindly provide the entire code for round() and get_float() functions

Comment: `round` is a standard library function declared in `math.h`, `get_float()` is a libcs50 function. Both of those functions will not cause any problems by themselves and do not require a source. @DeepakTatyajiAhire

Comment: `get_float` is  `cs50`.  Edited tags to reflect.

Comment: "it does not give the correct value." --> What incorrect value did it give?

Comment: It is not very polite to post a question, then disappear.  I do not see where you have taken the time to respond to any comments, or acknowledged whether or not the answer has helped you.  If you need to post a question, it would be better if you can wait until you have the time to interact with those trying to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop `left`, just use `cents`.

```
// left = cents-(quarters*25);
cents %= 25;
```

Remove `else` to check for quarters **and** dimes.

```
// else if (cents >= 10)
if (cents >= 10)
```

---

Likely other issues too.

Comment: On review, OP code is convoluted (which above answer helps straighten out), yet aside from a useful `'\n'` in printing, code looks OK.  Hmmm.